# Screenshots in Protractor jasmine 2 Html reporter

Tags: protractor

I am working on protractor and fetching report and screenshots of the test cases executed.But I am facing one issue in screenshot.I have enabled to take the screen shots only on failure. During the failure of the test case the screen shot file is generated but of 0 bytes. I want that the page on which the test failed should be captured in the screen shot. Please find my code below :
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

```
var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
dest: 'protractor-reports',
filename: 'protractor-report.html',
takeScreenshots: true,
takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true
```

//  screenshotsFolder: 'F:\Screeshots'
    });

```
exports.config = 
{
directconnect: true,
capabilities: {'browserName': 'chrome'},
framework: 'jasmine',
specs: ['example.js'],
jasmineNodeOpts: {
defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000
},
onPrepare: function() {
//Add a screenshot reporter and store screenshots to `/tmp/screenshots`:
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

  }
  }
```

Please let me know whats the issue and how can I solve it as I am new to this.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you able to generate report with below?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your conf file.

```
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

  onPrepare: function () {

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
        savePath: __dirname+'/qualityreports/testresults/e2e',
        takeScreenshots: true,
        takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
        filePrefix: 'automationReport',
        consolidate: true,
        cleanDestination: false,
        consolidateAll: true

      })
    );
},
```